# Defining a finite impartial game.

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I've been wondering how to abstractly describe a finite impartial game, and if there exists a standard way to do so, similar to how one would define a metric space $(M,d)$.

I've read this related question: [Definition of game in game theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128182/definition-of-game-in-game-theory)

However I'm not sure if this is a good solution, specially since I have no idea how to define the set of strategies and the payout function from only the rules of the game.

The game in question is played on a square board, where players may place pieces on squares depending on the number of placed pieces adjacent to said square. Is there any way to define a game from the board shape and the rules for placing pieces on squares, under normal play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An impartial game is just an acyclic directed graph, so you can use that definition from graph theory. Namely, an impartial game consists of

- A finite* set, $S$, of game states.
- A set, $M\subseteq S\times S$, of allowed moves. If $(s,t)\in M$, it means that you are allowed to move from $s$ to $t$.

This must satisfy the following property, ensuring the game has no cycles, so must end:

- For all $n\in \mathbb N$, there does not exist a sequence $(s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n)\in S^n$ where $(s_i,s_{i+1})\in M$ for each $i\in \{1,\dots,n-1\}$ and $(s_n,s_1)\in M$.

In your case, $S$ would be the set of subsets of your board, representing the places on the board occupied by pieces. You would say that $(s,t)\in M$ if $t$ has exactly one more element than $s$, and the unique element of $t\setminus s$ satisfies whatever local conditions you want to impose.

* You can remove the finite condition, but then you have to replace the "no cycles" condition with a "no infinite move sequences" condition. It seems finite is sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what i was looking for. I just have a question, how would I refer to the game itself, G = (S,M)?

Comment: Yes, $G=(S,M)$ works.

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding a discussion of the hereditarily finite sets that are often used for such games in Combinatorial Game Theory.

Comment: Do you also want a payoff function, or a definition of who wins? Or is the normal play rule (if you can't move, you lose) assumed?

Comment: @Trurl normal play is assumed. The comment was a bit late, since I've already had my work graded, thanks anyway, I appreciate it.  Right now I'm in the midst of translating most of the contents to English, as well as continuing the work I hadn't time to do.

Answer (score -2):

The economic sort of "game theory" as used in that link is not really related to the combinatorial "game theory" that studies impartial games and the like. The latter type of game has no chance and (at least in the classical versions) no payouts, only a winner and a loser. Normally to define a combinatorial game, we define the board and the rules of play, in essentially the way you would normally specify the rules of a game. I'm not sure what you mean by "abstractly" or why you refer to a metric space.

Comment: Downvoters: Why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: It's correct, just not helpful. I inferred from OP's mention of metric spaces that they wanted an axiomatic definition of a game, and you have no axioms. The only helpful sentence is " we define the board and the rules of play, in essentially the way you would normally specify the rules of a game", but this is too vague.

Comment: This seems more like a comment along the lines of "I think you used the wrong tag and your question is not clear to me". It's a good comment and not suitable as an answer.